# Java Find Duplicates in List and Map associated value to another List

Tags: java, list, hashmap

Suppose I have two lists.

```
List<List<Integer>> keysList;
List<Integer> valsList;
```

The intention of the two lists is that they are equal in size and that the element of each position in keysList is associated with the element of the same position in valsList. A sort of makeshift map except they are two Lists.

For example, element 0 in keysList may be `[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0]` and element 0 in valsList is `2` and they are associated with each other.

The problem is this: I am trying to make a third list, `List<List<Integer>> digitsList` where I place into this list a list of all integers from the valsList that match a certain key from the keysList.

For example, say that keysList has the following elements: `[0, 0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 2, 3, 5]` and valsList has '4, 2, 3'. Then is this case, I would like for digitsList to have `[4, 2], [3]`. The reason I have not used a HashMap for this is because a map cannot contain duplicate keys. But I am having a hard problem wrapping my head around logic that could solve this problem.

Comment: _"sort of makeshift map except they are two Lists"_ - this is known as "parallel arrays" and is from the 1960s when modern data structures existed only in Algol.  Do not do this, use a true Map.

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Stream API can be used for the solution:

1. Use `IntStream::range` to generate stream of indexes in `keyList` and `valueList`
2. Use `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.mapping` to convert lists into map - the keys are grouped, the values from `valueList` are collected into list

`LinkedHashMap` could be applied to keep the order of insertion.

3. Invoke `values()` of the resulting map to build the resulting list.
   Example:

```java
List<List<Integer>> keyList = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList(0, 0, 1, 2, 3), 
    Arrays.asList(0, 0, 1, 2, 3), 
    Arrays.asList(1, 0, 2, 3, 5)
);
List<Integer> valueList = Arrays.asList(4, 2, 3);

List<List<Integer>> digitList = new ArrayList<>(
    IntStream.range(0, keyList.size())
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        keyList::get,
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(valueList::get, Collectors.toList())
    ))
    .values());

System.out.println(digitList);
```

Output:

```
[[4, 2], [3]]
```

---

Similar solution without involving Stream API:

- build intermediate map `Map<List<Integer>, List<Integer>>`
- use `Map::computeIfAbsent` to create a list value in the intermediate map

```java
Map<List<Integer>, List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0, n = keyList.size(); i < n; i++) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(keyList.get(i), k -> new ArrayList<>())
       .add(valueList.get(i));
}
List<List<Integer>> digits = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

System.out.println(digits);
```